# How to insert bulk data into SQLite database in iOS using swift

Tags: ios, json, sqlite, swift, bulkinsert

I want to insert more than 20000 records to local database SQLite using Swift.I am getting data from json service.I am able to insert records successfully, but it is taking morethan 5 minutes to insert.I have searched a lot and implemented the begin and commit transactions, but i have not found any change in execution time. Below is the code:

```
func saveTeamDepartmentValueData(teamDepartmentValueArray : NSMutableArray) {
    var insertTeamDepartmentValueDataQuery : String = String()

    if (teamDepartmentValueArray.count > 0) {
        var errMsg:UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> = nil
        sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", nil, nil, &errMsg)

        insertTeamDepartmentValueDataQuery = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO store_feedback_form_kpi (team_id, department_id,value_id,ordinal,sub_category_id,team_department_value_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

        println("insertTeamDepartmentValueDataQuery is \(insertTeamDepartmentValueDataQuery)")
        var cSql = insertTeamDepartmentValueDataQuery.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var result:CInt=0
        var statement:COpaquePointer = nil
        var path = getPath()
        var dbpath = path.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let check = sqlite3_open(dbpath!, &database)
        var teamDepartmentValueDict : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, cSql!, -1, &statement, nil);

        for teamDepartmentValueDict in teamDepartmentValueArray
        {
            var teamDepartmentValueData : TeamDepartmentValue = TeamDepartmentValue ()
            if var teamId = teamDepartmentValueDict.valueForKey("team_id") as? String
            {
                teamDepartmentValueData.teamId = teamId.toInt()!
            }
            else{
                teamDepartmentValueData.teamId = 0
            }
            if var departmentId = teamDepartmentValueDict.valueForKey("department_id") as? String
            {
                teamDepartmentValueData.departmentId = departmentId.toInt()!
            }
            else{
                teamDepartmentValueData.departmentId = 0
            }
            if var valueId = teamDepartmentValueDict.valueForKey("value_id") as? String
            {
                teamDepartmentValueData.valueId = valueId.toInt()!
            }
            else{
                teamDepartmentValueData.valueId = 0
            }
            if var ordinal = teamDepartmentValueDict.valueForKey("ordinal") as? String
            {
                teamDepartmentValueData.ordinal = ordinal.toInt()!
            }
            else{
                teamDepartmentValueData.ordinal = 0
            }
            if var subCategoryId = teamDepartmentValueDict.valueForKey("sub_category_id") as? String
            {
                teamDepartmentValueData.subCategoryId = subCategoryId.toInt()!
            }
            else
            {
                teamDepartmentValueData.subCategoryId = 0
            }
            if var departmentValueId = teamDepartmentValueDict.valueForKey("team_department_value_id") as? String
            {
                teamDepartmentValueData.teamDepartmentValueId = departmentValueId.toInt()!
            }
            else{
                teamDepartmentValueData.teamDepartmentValueId = 0
            }

            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, CInt(1), CInt(teamDepartmentValueData.teamId))
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, CInt(2), CInt(teamDepartmentValueData.departmentId))
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, CInt(3), CInt(teamDepartmentValueData.valueId))
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, CInt(4), CInt(teamDepartmentValueData.ordinal))
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, CInt(5), CInt(teamDepartmentValueData.subCategoryId))
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, CInt(6), CInt(teamDepartmentValueData.teamDepartmentValueId))

            result = sqlite3_step(statement)

            if(result != SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                println("failed to insert")
            }
            else
            {
                println("inserted")
            }
            sqlite3_clear_bindings(statement);
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", nil, nil, &errMsg)
        sqlite3_exec(database, "END TRANSACTION",  nil, nil, &errMsg)
        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
        sqlite3_close(statement)
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exact answer to the problem.

As you have around 20000 records to insert it will take quite a long time. One thing that comes to my mind that could reduce time is using `dispatch_apply` method from GCD. You could check out `Performing Loop Iterations Concurrently` section of [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1) link.

With that you would be able to execute many loops concurrently on a concurrent queue. That could make your execution time shorter. I am not sure how much fast it will make, but you could give it a shot.

Also make sure not to execute each of your loop on separate task block but club them in considerable chunk to avoid unnecessary overhead of scheduling these tasks.